# Spark streaming job on YARN cluster mode stuck in accepted, then fails with a Timeout Exception

Tags: spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark streaming application that simply read messages from a Kafka topic, enrich them and then write the enriched messages in another kafka topic. 
I already tried it in Standalone mode (both client and cluster deploy mode) and in YARN client mode, successfully. 
When I submit the application in cluster mode it gives me the following messages:

```
18/01/10 12:13:34 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1515582681419_0001 to ResourceManager
18/01/10 12:13:34 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1515582681419_0001
18/01/10 12:13:35 INFO Client: Application report for application_1515582681419_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/01/10 12:13:35 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1515582814080
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://ambari1.internal:8088/proxy/application_1515582681419_0001/
     user: root
18/01/10 12:13:36 INFO Client: Application report for application_1515582681419_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/01/10 12:13:37 INFO Client: Application report for application_1515582681419_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

And keeps stuck in ACCEPTED Status until after around 4-5 minutes, exit with the following error message:

```
18/01/10 12:17:00 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1515583000000 ms
18/01/10 12:17:02 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:423)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:282)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:768)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:766)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
18/01/10 12:17:02 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds])
18/01/10 12:17:02 INFO StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
18/01/10 12:17:02 INFO ReceiverTracker: ReceiverTracker stopped
18/01/10 12:17:02 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately
```

Funny fact: If I visit the age of the application, I can see that the Spark Context has been started and it processes some messages.

Could anyone help me on this? 
PS: These are the resources of my YARN cluster:
[image: ClusterYARN]

Comment: ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM. 
even if I increase the `spark.yarn.am.waitTime`... no luck

Comment: Any update on this? I have also same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with Yarn "App Timeline Server". Try to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating your spark session with master as local?. Please do check this.